# How to convert SOMETHING.php to INDEX.php?site=SOMETHING

Tags: php

I've got an website in php. I've got a question. I've got a few files like rules.php contact.php

The site looking like site.com/rules.php etc
how to make something like: site.com/index.php?=rules

I don't know I wrote the second version correctly.

Comment: it's called a mod rewrite

Comment: Or you're perhaps just asking for some form of front controller / dispatcher. The attributes are called QUERY_STRING or GET parameters, and a simple `switch` often suffices.

Comment: What's your webserver?

Answer (score 0):

a simple method to achive this is to use [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) with the value you get with your query string using `$_REQUEST`

in index.php you would have

```
<h1>your called page</h1>
<?php 
    if($_REQUEST['file'] != "")
    {
        include $_REQUEST['file'].".php";
    }
?>
<p>end of index.php</p>
```

in your rules.php page you would have

```
<p>obey the S.Ex G'ods</p>
```

then you call index.php with the following

```
site.com/index.php?file=rules
```

and you'll see whatever content is on rules.php will be displayed in index.php between the `<h1>` and `<p>`

[image: Stack Exchange Global Mods]

you can then expand on this so you don't have to provide the file path or specifying codes that are looked up in the database<sup>1</sup>

---

<sup>1: don't forget to [sanitize](https://xkcd.com/327/)</sup>